# Powershell form: how can I find controls based on name-property

Tags: winforms, powershell

How can I list all the controls in my form where (name)-property begins with something spesific and then use it in a foreach?

I have multiple `groupboxes` under multiple `tabpages` where the `name` starts with `gbs` *(Example: gbs1, gbs2, gbs3 ++)*. Now I want to disable all the groupeboxes that begins with `gbs*` at say a click of a botton without having to list all the groupboxes manually.

I've tried to look it up, but I can't find good documentation on it. I might be searching for the wrong words...

I'm guessing this is a start, and it's as far as I've come, but I'm not sure where to go from here or if I'm way off;

```
$list = @($MainForm.Controls.Find -like 'gbs*')

foreach ($item in $list){$item.enabled = $false} #Just a example of what I'm thinking
```

---

Purpose: 
I am creating a .exe form that is going to automate active directory. The form contains a bunch of settings, and all of them is within these groupboxes. I’m going to have a ‘edit-mode’, so that when it’s active - the groupboxes are enabled. When not, disabled.

---

Solution, thanks to help from @Clijsters :

```
    #Get all the tabpages
    $script:tabpages = $tabTasks.Controls | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "tp*" } | select Name, Controls
    $script:tabpages += $tabSettings.Controls | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "tp*" } | select Name, Controls

    #Get groupboxes in tabpages
    $script:groupboxes = [System.Object]$tabpages.Controls

    #Disable
    $groupboxes | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "gbs*" } | ForEach-Object { $_.Enabled = $true }
```

Comment: So you're searching for something like `$list = $MainForm.childNodes | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "gbs*"}` ?

Comment: ...And what is the context of your script? An Internet Explorer instance? `Invoke-WebRequest`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Clijsters. It's a program that are automating active directory in a bunch of ways. What I'm trying to do is have this 'edit-mode' where all groupboxes containing settings (it's a lot of settings) will be disabled or enabled weather you're in the edit mode or not. --- I tried  `$MainForm.Controls | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "gbs*" }` which does give me a list, great! However, I thought by using `$mainform` it would include tabpages and such, which it doesn't seem to do. Most of the groupboxes are in tabpages. I'll test some more of course.

Comment: Funny - I thoutght of HTML content, not a forms app. Please tag your question accordingly and I'm sure some more answerees and commenters will appear! tabpages have their own Controls container. Add some more code to your question that we can help you with that and it'll be more clear how your form is organized

Comment: My bad, I will add some more info soon. Thanks!

Comment: Hint to your edit: Shouldn't `-ExpandProperty` be your friend for the tabpages controls?

Comment: Oh, you sure are right about that, @Clijsters. Good point! I'm fairly new to powershell, so the things I learn still keep jumping out of my brain every now and then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For finding Items in a list, [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-5.1) is your CmdLet of choice!

In your case something like

```
$list = $MainForm.Controls | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "gbs*"}
```

will work fine. You can store the result in a variable (like shown above) and use it in `foreach` or pipe the resulting list directly to [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-5.1) and process it there like below:

```
$MainForm.Controls | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "gbs*"} | ForEach-Object {Do Something}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've been playing around with this, also in tabpages (which you told me had it's own container) - and I'm now able to list all the groupboxes within tabpages and work with them with ForEach-Object. This is perfect, thanks yet again!

Comment: Nice! You're welcome. How did you go through the tabpages Controls?

Comment: I added the piece of code that I ended up with to the bottom of the question now for you to see :) _(it would be a bit long and messy to explain in a comment - and maybe someone else will find it useful)._